# progress Dialog simpel

Tags: android, progressdialog

i want to add a progress Dialog button when i click on this button before the new activity apperar, i think i don't need a thread, i did search but i find only that i need to do a thread and many other think it s not clear 
i just want when i clik on  a progress Dialog say to the user to wait so a few sec the other activity will appear that's all:

```
btn_newsfeed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Launching News Feed Screen
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CustomizedListView.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: but whts the need to make user wait?

Comment: the customizedlist view java will read some info from a database

Comment: Use Asynchronous Task, refer this http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/07/load-listview-in-background-asynctask.html

Answer (score 0):

There are three different different ways in which you can use a ProgressDailog -using threads, handlers and async tasks. 
here a example of async task for using a progress Dialog

```
    private class Operation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

          @Override
          protected String doInBackground(String... params)
 {
// code to be executed in background thread 
                for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                return "Executed";
          }      

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
// runs on UI thread and updated UI after executing doInBackground
                progressDialog.dismiss();
          }

          @Override
          protected void onPreExecute() {
ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Title ", "Loading...");
              progressDialog.show();

          }

          @Override
          protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
// runs on UI thread and starts first

          }
    }
```

Comment: I've removed your 'example', as it is an undisclosed link to your own blog. Edit that back in, or continue to post answers like this, and they are likely to be flagged as spam.